# Is there experimental evidence that people ever play mixed Nash equilibrium in real games?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Have any studies been done that demonstrate people (not game theorists) actually using mixed Nash equilibrium as their strategy in a game?

Comment: people in the everyday life are not rational while the Nash eq. is based on the assumption of the rationality. If one of the players irrational then it can make a bad joke for the outcome of others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://pricetheory.uchicago.edu/levitt/Papers/ChiapporiGrosecloseLevitt2002.pdf)(article about mixed equilibrium strategies), I think penalty kicks between two soccer teams use mixed Nash equilibrium strategies.

Comment: I let this question go for a while hoping for some polarization between the answers to develop in order to help me know which one is the best. After a lot of thought, I think it is this one. I would like to have seen some quotes from the article that might help this answer be easier to interpret a "yes there is evidence" or "no there is not" from, with reference(s) to support. Ultimately this seems to be the most direct answer though and it gives a specific study like I ask for. Unfortunately that study still seems subject to speculation as to what extent players use Nash equilibrium.

Answer (score 3):

There have been lots of studies on this sort of thing, with different results.  It depends a lot on cultural context.  You might look at ["A Beautiful Math"](http://books.google.ca/books?id=0NKfbdyzvJAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22A%20beautiful%20math%22%20siegfried&hl=en&ei=AOylTcDFPJLmsQOF9bn6DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Tom Siegfried

Comment: I was intrigued by "There have been lots of studies". Some references would be great. The resource you provided does seem very good in general, however, I (and others who want a answer to this question) would need to buy it in order to explore if it does in fact answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> **This would be a fantastic question for a** [Game Theory StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory?referrer=MGta8a5T8SlJlb1swuXPYQ2)

My preliminary research backs up my intuition: **it depends**. Specifically, it depends on whether there is sufficient common knowledge to foster a gradient-like movement to mixed-equilibria.

[Learning a Mixed Strategy Equilibrium in the Laboratory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167268194901082) by Bloomfeld (1994)

> Literature [on the evolution of behavior] raises doubts about the
>   predictive power of mixed strategy equilibria, because very few
>   mechanical processes converge to such outcomes. However, mixed
>   strategy equilibria may have more predictive power when the feedback
>   players receive is disclosed publicly. Such disclosure allows players
>   to predict and exploit mechanical adjustments, and may therefore
>   induce players to apply more sophistivated adjustment strategies that
>   do converge to equilibrium.

[An Experimental Study of Information and Mixed-Strategy Play in the Three-Person Matching-Pennies Game](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001990050020) by McCabe, Mukherji and Runkle (2000)

> Recent experiments on mixed-strategy play in experimental games reject
>   the hypothesis that subjects play a mixed strategy even when that
>   strategy is the unique Nash equilibrium prediction. However, in a
>   three-person matchingpennies game played with perfect monitoring and
>   complete payoff information, we cannot reject the hypothesis that
>   subjects play the mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium.

[How do People Play Against Nash Opponents?](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1803430) by Shachat, Swarthout, Wei  (2011)

> We examine experimentally how humans behave when they play against a
>   computer which implements its part of a mixed strategy Nash
>   equilibrium ... A minority of subjects' play was consistent with their
>   Nash equilibrium strategy.